# NameError in Python with the return variable from a function

Tags: python, nameerror

The function FindACar works actually good. It does what I want. But there is only one problem, which doesn't happen very frequently, but it happens sometimes. The error I get is: "NameError: name randomchoice is not defined". I don't understand why. I've tried to make randomchoice as a golobal variable, but it didn't work out.

What's wrong with this "randomchoice" in my code?

```
Car_Auswahl = FindACar(bins,Price_List,Car_for_select)

def FindACar(bins,Price_List,Car_for_select):
    # global randomchoice
    choice_idx = [] #Initialisierung der Auswahl des Autos
    shape,scale = 4.2531, 7896.8 
    coeff = 1.1299564124727026  # = Car['Preis'].mean()/((ReadPreisList['avg']*ReadPreisList['Anzahl']).sum()/ReadPreisList['Anzahl'].sum())
    sample = np.random.gamma(shape, scale)*coeff 
    while sample < min(Price_List) :
        sample = np.random.gamma(shape, scale)*coeff    
    bin_idx = np.digitize(sample,bins) 
    if  0 < bin_idx < len(bins):
        for index, row in Car_for_select.iterrows():
            if bins[bin_idx-1] < row.Preis <= bins[bin_idx]:
                choice_idx.append(index) 
            else:
                pass
        if len(choice_idx) != 0:
            randomchoice = np.random.choice(choice_idx) 
    else:
        target = min(Price_List, key=lambda x:abs(x-sample)) 
        randomchoice = Price_List.index(target)
    return randomchoice
```

Comment: Is there a possible path through your program where `randomchoice` is never assigned a value before you attempt to return it? For example, if `len(choice_idx)` is 0?

Comment: You have a lot of conditionals that can prevent `randomchoice` from ever being set in the first place.

Comment: Hi @chepner, could you give me a bit more ideas?